# Creating a game that can inject modifications

Tags: java, android

**The Situation:**

**I am developing a proof of concept Android and PC game that will actually function as a base sandbox alone, and the actual "game" is a mod that is layered on top of the provided sandbox.  What I cannot figure out is how exactly to inject the developers code into my application's instance.**

The mod needs to be *loaded* into an already running instance of the sandbox, rather than being a compiled rewrite and redistribution of my original applications class files.  And, while the mod will introduce it's own code, it is expected that the developer will be required to work within certain boundaries of the given sandbox's infrastructure.

**My Conceived Solution:**

I felt that the best solution would be to create a library along side the sandbox.  The library would contain classes and interfaces that the sandbox would understand how to call upon, and by extension and implementation the developer could program classes that could fit into the code as one of it's own while also being able to instantiate outer classes implemented by the developer.

**The Issue:**

The problem lies in the execution I have planned for this concept.  *The vision* is that a person could download a mod, move it to a mods\ folder, start up my application, click "play game" followed by a drop down menu of all the playable mod files in the mods\ folder, and load it on the spot to play.  Each game will use a UI style that is familiar, the base graphical architecture will be familiar, button responsiveness, player or unit movement, hud, icon sorting, will all be of a familiar and predictable flair, but each mod will have a unique actual gameplay experience from the mind of a completely separate developer.  *What I cannot figure out* is how to dynamically inject code from a separate developer into my original application and it be recognized, since it is neither in the classpath nor in any of my original packages.

Comment: Have You checked http://android-developers.blogspot.kr/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple: Put a configuration file into the mod, and that configuration file specifies the "main" class of the mod.

Your sandbox just needs to obtain the info, create a class loader for the mod's class path, load that main class and invoke its starting method (you define the signature/or interface it needs to implement).

Comment: I think that this is definitely a direction to go.  I did some reading on the classloaders that come with Java and android, and I believe that this is a simple and brilliant way to execute this.  I'm going to work on proving this idea, but for now I for believe that this is the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

Technically you could use [DexClassLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.html).

Legally your app may conflict with [Google Play Policy](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html) regarding self-modifying code.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll research the DexClassLoader.  And, also, thank you for reminding me about the google play policy.